# How to access a function via DOM?

Tags: javascript

How to edit a function inside js file via Dom, let's say that we have :

```
<script>
    if(GlobalVariable == true)
    //do something
</script>
```

And in another example we have

```
function add(a,b) {
return a>b;
}
```

how can I access via DOM first example to edit GlobalVariable to false, and second function to return b>a .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you want to do this, and why do you think you want to do it *via the DOM*?

Answer (score 1):

> ...via DOM...

You can't. When the `script` element is evaluated, the code within it is run immediately (unless `defer` or `async` are used), at which point, the code has already run / the function has already been created. (Even if `async` or `defer`is used, you can't change the code loaded by the element prior to that code being executed.)

In the second example, you could replace the function, just not via the DOM:

```
add = function(a, b) { return b > a; } // "add" seems like a REALLY odd name though
```

...since the binding (loosely, "variable") created by `function add() { ... }` is writable.

You can't change the `if` though, not least because it's already been run.

Comment: i thought that may be with document.scripts ... we can access what is inside

Comment: @salmanaacvf - Nope. :-) It **is** possible to access the text of the script within a `script` element **if** it's inline (not `src=...`), but modifying that text doesn't do anything to the code that was created by parsing and running it.